# SSRS has any page limit to render?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a dataset of 4 million records. Ideally a page should contain 40 rows maximum. So is it possible to generate 100000+ pages of data using ssrs?

For me I waited for 2 hours, still it is not generated. Can anyone say ssrs has any limit?

Comment: A report with 100000 pages of details? What are you really trying to do because this sounds like an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is taken from the SSRS documentation

> When you run a report, report size is equal to the amount of data that is returned in the report plus the size of the
> output stream. Reporting Services does not impose a maximum limit on the size of a rendered report.System
> memory determines the upper limit on size(by default,a report server uses all available configured memory when
> rendering a report), but you can specify configuration settings to set memory thresholds and memory
> management policies

However, I would question the usefulness of a report with 100,000+ pages. Who would look at it?